# Dereferencing iterator to pointers correctly

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, dereference

I have a vector of pointers to objects. Each object stores a value and has a toString() function that returns that value as a string. I have an iterator to go through the vector and I need to extract the value of each object by calling toString(). The problem is, I can't figure out how to get the value.

This function is ultimately supposed to write the number to a file, but I'm using the cout for testing.

```
    void writeNumbers(vector<Integer*>& input)
    {
        ofstream write;
        write.open("Integers.txt");
        vector<Integer*>::iterator iter = input.begin();
        for (iter; iter < input.end(); iter++)
        {
            **std::cout << (*iter)->toString() << std::endl;**
        }
        write.close();

I get an Access Violation error which points me to the toString() function:

    std::string Integer::toString()
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << *(this)->value;
        return ss.str();
    }

toString() works fine whenever I don't try to access it through the iterator.
```

Edit: Value in toString is actually a pointer to a number.

Edit2: New writeNumbers:

```
void writeNumbers(vector<Integer*>& input)
{
    ofstream write;
    write.open("Integers.txt");
    vector<Integer*>::iterator iter = input.begin();
    for (iter; iter != input.end(); iter++)
    {
        std::cout << (*iter)->toString() << std::endl;
    }
    write.close();
}
```

**Final Edit**: Alright, the problem turned out to be a borked constructor that was failing to initialize a pointer properly, so I was WAY off base on where the problem actually was. :)

```
Integer::Integer(string input)
{
if(isNaN(input))
value = new int(atoi(input.c_str()));
}
```

So it **should** have been !isNaN, plus I fixed the problem of initializing it on bad input:

```
//New constructor, works 100%
Integer::Integer(string input)
{
if(!isNaN(input))
    value = new int(atoi(input.c_str()));
else
    value = new int(0);
}
```

Comment: I think this code wouldn't compile, much less give an access violation.  Unless you wrote `int* Integer::operator->()` somewhere

Answer (score 2):

Your toSting() has the issue. Change

`ss <<*(this)->value;`

to

```
ss << value;
```

Comment: This is my fault for failing to mention it, but value is actually a pointer.

Comment: Expanding on that, if I pass the pointer, it works but it of course passes the address and not the value I need. Any attempts to dereference to pass into the stringstream causes the access error.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This is not an error, but a general advice when using iterators. Dont use `<` to check for end, use `!=`.

```
iter < input.end()
```

It should be like this:

```
iter != input.end()
```

This is because for certain containers, the < operator will not do what you expect. As a result, at some point you could be dereferencing input.end() itself, which points at nothing.

Comment: `std::vector` has random access iterators. `<` will work just fine, although `!=` is more idiomatic.

Comment: @PeteBecker is that really mandated by the standard, or is it implementation defined?

Comment: Yes, obviously, random access iterators for `std::vector` are mandated.

Comment: @PeteBecker - I did, and in case anybody else is looking for this: the comparison (with the expected result) is guaranteed to work for random acces iterators. (Note: bidirectional is not enough here)

Comment: @Axel - " (Note: bidirectional is not enough here)" - right. And that's why `!=` is more idiomatic; although `<` works here, changing the iterator type (by, for example, changing the container type) could invalidate it. `!=` works for all iterator types.

Comment: @W.Goeman I fixed it but it doesn't solve anything. The error occurs the very first time it goes into the loop, not at the end.

Comment: Edited the answer according to the comments.